# Thesis CLS file instead of llncs

Tags: thesis, lncs

I have written a paper with a `llncs.cls` file.

I was asked to use a different class file which is more suitable for a thesis.

I have tried looking for such a file, the best I managed to find was mitthesis.cls but I had many compilation errors regarding environment undefined (Theorem, Lemma, remark  etc...).

I would appreciate help with a reference to a suitable class file

Comment: With so many specifications ... indeed `book.cls`,  `scrbook.cls` or `memoir.cls`. But if you want more oriented alternatives: https://ctan.org/topic/dissertation, https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/ https://www.latextemplates.com/cat/theses, https://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis, https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/thesis, etc. Google is your friend.

Comment: I forgot to mention that thesis templates are often garbage that doesn't work well or have a horrible design. If you don't have an official template from your university, my suggestion is to start from scratch with the above standard book-like classes.

Comment: Try the `memoir` class. The manual (`> texdoc memoir`) has an extensive chapter on **An Example Thesis Design**.